# Distribution and origin of reflexive pronouns like "myself" across languages

Tags: grammar, linguistic-typology

*I'm neither a professional linguist nor a native English speaker, please excuse me if I use any term incorrectly. Feel free to make and suggest edits to make my question more clear.*

---

## Question

Hello,

I was teaching Polish to a Chinese girl and she was really confused by **uczę** and **uczę się** construct, which translate literally to **I teach** and **I teach myself**. That seemed interesting to me, because out of 3 European languages I know, each one of them has an analogous *grammatical marker indicating the action is done both by and to a subject*: **sich** in German, **myself** in English and **się** in Polish. Using Google Translate I found that **mismo** in Spanish and **même** in French fill the same role.

Thus here is my question:

1. is **myself**, **sich**, **się** and it's analogues in different languages a feature specific to European/Indo-European languages or is it a peculiarity of Chinese language that it has no such construct?
2. in Chinese, how would I modify a verb to indicate I'm doing something to myself as opposed to unspecified object? Using Gogle Translate again it seems that every pair of **verb**/**verb myself** I try uses a separate verb, similar to **learn**/**teach** in English.

---

## EDIT:

It was brought to my attention that Chinese (at least Mandarin Chinese) **does** in fact have a reflexive pronoun and it was just a misunderstanding between me and my Chinese student. Nevertheless I still find this question interesting, so let me rephrase it

1. are there any languages or language families that do not have a reflexive pronoun and if so, how do they work around this issue?

Comment: This is called a _reflexive_ pronoun. Chinese does have one: 自己  (in Mandarin _zìjǐ_)

Comment: @Michaelyus thank you, I corrected my question to include your comment

Comment: "me in French" -> "même in French"

Comment: German, English, Slavic and Romance reflexives each actually work differently.  English especially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in fact a well-researched question in linguistic typology, for a high-level overview see [WALS chapter 47](https://wals.info/chapter/47). Not every language has reflexive pronouns, sometimes so-called *intensifiers* fill the gap. The introduction of the WALS chapter has very instructive examples of that.

EDIT: And yes, Chinese is different from the European languages in respect  to reflexive pronouns: While European languages have different expressions for reflexive pronouns and intensifiers, Chinese lacks that distinction.

Comment: Varieties of Chinese behave like English, Dutch, and the Scandinavian forms of Germanic in this respect!

Comment: @Michaelyus: From a European perspective, you just listed the outliers :-) See the [chart for the WALS chapter](https://wals.info/feature/47A#2/21.0/148.4)